# ItemsControl with WinForms TextBoxes inside WindowsFormsHost with more than 2520 lines causes a rendering gap

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Scrollviewer with an ItemsControl inside. Each Item is a **Windows Forms** Textbox.

When the ItemsControl with the 4 Textboxes there is a big vertical gap/space between the textboxes.

This error does not happen with a **WPF** TextBox control!

Why is there the gap? And when I scroll the ItemsControl content overflows its borders that should also not happen

The gap is visible with exactly 2521 lines of this sentence:

```
"Why there the green gap above the Textbox when there is too much text, I have not yet found the line count causing the gap !"
```

When there are less lines then there is not gap ???

I have attached a sample repro VS 2010 solution here:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/y85fwv

and see the error for yourself please!

**VIEW**

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"    
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:ExpanderTest"
        >  
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40px"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Orange">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button>Test</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorLogs}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                                                       
                                <!--<Expander Header="{Binding FileName}" Background="Green">-->
                                    <Controls:BindableTextBox Text="{Binding Document}" />
                                <!--</Expander>-->                           
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Embed a WinForms TextBox and make it MVVM ready to be bound:**

```
public class BindableTextBox : WindowsFormsHost
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

        public BindableTextBox()
        {
            textBox.Multiline = true;
            textBox.WordWrap = true;
            //textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            //textBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            this.Child = textBox;           

            //textBox.Height = textBox.Parent.Height;
            //textBox.Width = textBox.Parent.Width;

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BindableTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata("",
              new PropertyChangedCallback((d, e) =>
              {
                  var myTextBox = d as BindableTextBox;
                  if (myTextBox != null && myTextBox.textBox != null)
                      myTextBox.textBox.Text = myTextBox.GetValue(e.Property) as string;
              }), null));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            GetErrorLogs();
        }

        private void GetErrorLogs()
        {
            string executingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(executingDirectory + "\\Log", "*.log");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {

                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                        var e = new ErrorLogViewModel
                        {
                            FileName = "ErrorLog ",
                            Document = text,
                        };
                        ErrorLogs.Add(e);

            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel> _errorLogs = new ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel> ErrorLogs
        {
            get { return _errorLogs; }
            set
            {
                _errorLogs = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorLogs");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the sense in having a WinForms TextBox in a WPF application?

Comment: Clemens believe me there is a sense. Because the f***ing Textbox in WPF is slow as hell. My UI freezes when I bind to 5000 lines of log text with multiple logs. Background workers does not help here (which I use) its just the binding is too slow. The binding of the WinForms TextBox is 10 times faster - not kidding - I have attached a sample repro Clemens, your the WPF dude please have a look :-)

Comment: And these 5000 lines of log text should be editable? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: And you think that using a Winforms `TextBox` and a `WindowsFormsHost` will be quicker than a WPF `TextBox`? What about the overhead of using the `WindowsFormsHost` elements?

Comment: @Clemens NO its just for display NOT EDIT!

Comment: No need to shout! Then why use a TextBox *at all*. Use a TextBlock instead.

Comment: @Sheridan YES WinForms is faster I have SEEN it! I sit on .NET 3.5!

Comment: @Clemens sorry for shout was not my intention rather a formatting thing... I have tried TextBox, TextBlock, Label all are slow.